# How to use AND/OR in a conditional reverse polish notation formula?

Tags: java, math, rpn, shunting-yard

Assume I have a condition in the form of "(a > b) OR (c < d)". How can I convert it to reverse polish notation and calculate it? I gave it a try by setting the "and/or" tokens at the lowest precedence level and got "a b c OR > d <". Is it right?

Basically I want to add conditional features to this implementation of the shunting yard algorithm; http://eddmann.com/posts/shunting-yard-implementation-in-java/

Comment: Operator goes after operands.  So: a b > for (a > b).  For all of it: a b > c d < OR.  Not really sure this is a programming question though.

Comment: I'm working on a Shunting Yard algorithm based on this implementation; http://eddmann.com/posts/shunting-yard-implementation-in-java/

Comment: And yes, it looks like I just had to change the level of precedence of the conditional tokens. It makes much more sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(a > b) OR (c < d) in RPN:

a b > c d < OR

Make sure you read left-to-right:

[Post Fix Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm)